# How do I make my windows minimize like a Mac in classic Gnome?

Tags: gnome, compiz, customization, window

How do I make my ubuntu windows do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something similar was recently blogged by [OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/get-the-os-x-genie-effect-in-compiz-easily/) - it involves running a binary from the developer, together with editing compiz settings.

The binary manipulates the standard Compiz Magic Lamp effect which does something similar to what you want but is not as "slick" as MacOS.

If you really want to install random binaries - not a good idea from a security point of view, following the instructions below reproduced from the blog:

- Download [this file](http://ubuntuone.com/p/k8O/)
- Right click on it and choose ‘properties > permissions’ and allow it to ‘execute’ as a  programme by checking the relevant box
- Now open a terminal and enter:

  ```
  sudo ./genie_compiz
  ```
- Open up CompizConfig Settings and proceed to edit the ‘MagicLamp’ effect values as per the screenshots on [Placidio’s blog](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=es&tl=en&u=http://enalpha.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/efecto-genie-macos-en-compiz-de-manera%25C2%25A0sencilla/&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com).
- Restart Compiz via the terminal using:

  ```
  compiz –replace &
  ```

Comment: Link is broken now